# CommonCrypto to generate encrypted string with 16 char length

Tags: swift, encryption, commoncrypto

It is the first time I try to use encryption so I am not sure if what I need is achievable with the following code.

**MY PROBLEM** - I need it to generate an encoded string with 16 characters  instead of the 64 character that is being generated at the moment.

I have a preference for using a native swift library instead of an external framework. And because of that could not find much about how to use CommonCrypto. Not sure if it is correct approach as well.

**Where I got the example**

http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.nz/2016/02/resurrecting-commoncrypto-in-swift-for.html

**My usage**

```
let keyString = "1234567812345678"
    let message = "12345678123456781234567812345678"
    let iv = "iv-salt-string--" // string of 16 characters in length

    let encoded = message.aesEncrypt(keyString, iv: iv)!
    print("encoded -> \(encoded)")

    let unencode = encoded.aesDecrypt(keyString, iv: iv)!
    print("unencode -> \(unencode)")
```

**Output**

```
encoded -> S81qV6F31xO8mUA1+HhsF7pHOMeE0f6Bbcmj3Zzk3EFLhQTCmfYlouorrUkYKL6K
unencode -> 12345678123456781234567812345678
```

**Extension**

```
extension String {

    func aesEncrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
            data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
            cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {


                let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
                let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
                let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
                let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)



                var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

                let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                    algoritm,
                    options,
                    keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                    iv,
                    data.bytes, data.length,
                    cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                    &numBytesEncrypted)

                if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                    cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                    let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
                    return base64cryptString


                }
                else {
                    return nil
                }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func aesDecrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
            data = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters),
            cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

                let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
                let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
                let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
                let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

                var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

                let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                    algoritm,
                    options,
                    keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                    iv,
                    data.bytes, data.length,
                    cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                    &numBytesEncrypted)

                if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                    cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                    let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    return unencryptedMessage
                }
                else {
                    return nil
                }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 16 bytes of input after converting to data from hex. You specify PKCS#7 padding `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding`. If the data is an exact multiple of the block size PKCS#7 padding must add an entire block of padding to the data to be encrypted making 32-bytes of data. (That is because some padding must always be added and if there is no partial block the only way is to add a block of padding.) On decryption the 16-bytes of padding will be removed so you will get back 16-bytes of data.

See: [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

If the input data is **always** a multiple of the block size (16-bytes) then you do  not need to add padding, so you do not need to supply the `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` as an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {

func aesEncrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
    if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.count)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {


        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)



        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                  algoritm,
                                  options,
                                  (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                  iv,
                                  (data as NSData).bytes, data.count,
                                  cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
            return base64cryptString


        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func aesDecrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
    if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let data = NSData(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                  algoritm,
                                  options,
                                  (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                  iv,
                                  data.bytes, data.length,
                                  cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
            return unencryptedMessage
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}


  }
```

Is this 16 bit of length